# foreach in C# recalculation

Tags: c#

If I write a foreach statment in C#:

```
foreach(String a in veryComplicatedFunction())
{

}
```

Will it calculate veryComplicatedFunction every iteration or only once, and store it somewhere?

Comment: You could add a Debug.WriteLine() to veryComplicatedFunction() and find out for yourself!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your question is answered by section [12.9.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1295-the-foreach-statement) of the specification, which states:

---

> The above steps, if successful,
> unambiguously produce a collection
> type C, enumerator type E and element
> type T. A foreach statement of the
> form

```
foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
```

> is then expanded to:

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        V v;
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            embedded-statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        … // Dispose e
    }
}
```

---

As you can see, in the expansion the expression x is only evaluated once.

Answer (score 21):

It will only calculate it once

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you mean by once. If you have a method like the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> veryComplicatedFunction()
{
    List<string> l = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
    foreach (var item in l)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Control would be returned to the method calling veryComplicatedFunction after each yield. So if they were sharing List l then you could have some strange results. A sure fire way to remove that kind of problem would be calling the ToArray extension on the veryComplicatedFunction.

Answer (score 5):

`veryComplicatedFunction` likely returns [`IEnumerable<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), which should mean that it's calculations are performed only once and it streams its results in some way. However, without seeing the actual method, there is no way to guarantee what it does. What is guaranteed is that `veryComplicatedFunction` is only called once, what the `foreach` does is iterate through the returns of a method.

Answer (score 1):

It should calculate it just once. As a side note the verycomplicatedfunction() must return an `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` or any object which has a public GetEnumerator() method.

Comment: Um actually your side note isn't correct. As long as it returns an object that has a GetEnumerator method that takes no parameters and returns an IEnumerator or derivation thereof, it will work with the foreach statement. The class itself does not need to implement IEnumerable.

Comment: Geez you're right. I'll correct my answer. I was under the impression that in order to do a foreach the underlying type must be an IEnumerable. Looks like the compiler is happy as long as there is a public definition of GetEnumerator() available. Interesting...

Comment: One example of duck-typing in .net ;-)
(I think there are no others yet)

Comment: It's not duck-typing, as the compiler checks for the existence of the method.  It is an example of structural-subtyping, instead of the more commonly known named-subtyping.

Answer (score 0):

If it calculated it each time, it could cause a world of pain if your function was based on something dynamic such as the current time.  It should calculate it once.